# Installing iPDC Unix Programme

Tags: unix, makefile

I am trying to install [iPDC](http://ipdc.codeplex.com) on a Centos unix laptop.

I am getting a make error when I attempt to install the programme - I have attached a screenshot of my problem.

[image: Command run: sudo make install]

The command run is `sudo make install` and I am attempting to install as the `root` user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your installed GTK version is probably too old to support this software.  GtkBuilder (a component within GTK) showed up at version 2.12.  To find out what version you have, run `pkg-config --modversion gtk+-2.0` at the command line.  But that version has been around for quite some time.  What version Centos are you running?  I assume 5, which is quite old.

Upgrading GTK can be tricky, as most of your desktop software relies on it.  If you're in for an adventure, the "easiest" would be to upgrade your Centos OS (to 6.x).  You might be able to compile a more recent GTK from source and keep it separate from your system GTK, but that will take some patience.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that GTK is not installed.

Try something like: `yum install gtk2` or `yum install gtk2-devel`

Comment: That worked, to a certain degree.  I now do not see the top 7 lines, but the rest of the errors are still present.

Comment: You don't see the top 7 lines because those files compiled cleanly the first time, and `make` is smart enough not to recompile them this time.

Comment: Then I am still getting an error, but installing gtk2 placed the files in a folder `gtk-2.0/gtk/gtk.h` but the source is looking for `gtk/gtk/gtk.h`and changing the location does not work.

Comment: Your error message doesn't say "gtk.h not found", so it appears that the issue is that your GTK is missing something important.  See my answer.